# Question on in and out states in chapter 10 of Weinberg's QFT volume 1

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering

In chapter 10 section 2 (on pomology) of Weinberg's QFT volume 1, he shows $G$ has a pole when the external line goes on shell. In the proof, he inserted a complete set of single-particle states $\Psi_{\textbf{p},\sigma}$ of the full theory.

Later in the chapter, he used this theorem to prove the LSZ reduction formula. It seems to me that in order to prove the LSZ reduction formula,the single-particle states inserted should be in/out states $\Psi_{\textbf{p},\sigma}^{\,\pm}$. On page 430, he had footnote saying that $\Psi_{\textbf{p},\sigma}=\Psi_{\textbf{p},\sigma}^{\,+}=\Psi_{\textbf{p},\sigma}^{\,-}$ in our case due to the absence of external varying field. Can anyone explain to me what he means here? It seems to me that $\Psi_{\textbf{p},\sigma}^{\,+}\neq\Psi_{\textbf{p},\sigma}^{\,-}$ should  be the case in a general interacting theory.